# How to calculate number of pixels within selected contour in python

Tags: python, opencv, contour

I want to calculate selected area. I have a formula but I need to calculate number of pixels in the contour. 
How can I do ?

Here is my code;

```
import os
import cv2
import logging
import numpy as np
from imageio import imread
import matplotlib
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import morphsnakes as ms

    def _____():

    # Load the image.
    img = imread(PATH_IMG_NODULE)[..., 0] / 255.0

    # g(I)
    gimg = ms.inverse_gaussian_gradient(img, alpha=1000, sigma=5.48)

    # Initialization of the level-set.
    init_ls = ms.circle_level_set(img.shape, (100, 126), 20)

    # Callback for visual plotting
    callback = visual_callback_2d(img)

    # MorphGAC.
    ms.morphological_geodesic_active_contour(gimg, iterations=45,
                                             init_level_set=init_ls,
                                             smoothing=1, threshold=0.31,
                                             balloon=1, iter_callback=callback)
```

Here is my selected area's picture;

[image: Selected Area]

Thank you.

Comment: what's the format of the data that represents your contour?

Comment: Are you asking image's type ? I don't understand. @lenik

Comment: Overlay your contour on a black background image. Then use np.count_nonzero(). See https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.count_nonzero.html

Comment: Yeah, thanks for this document. But I don't understand how should I apply  `np.count_nonzero()` to my code. Here you can see all codes. [link](https://github.com/pmneila/morphsnakes/blob/master/examples.py)

Comment: Do you want to count only the pixels that fall along the contour or all pixels inside the contour. For the latter, you can get the area of the contour (in pixels) from cv2.contourArea()

Comment: Since you have the contour outline you can simply draw this onto a blank mask then count the number of pixels. `mask = np.zeros(image.shape, dtype=np.uint8)` then draw it onto mask with `cv2.drawContours()` then either use `np.count_nonzero()` or `cv2.countNonZero()` on the mask

Comment: @fmw42 From the doc on [`contourArea`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.2.0/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#ga2c759ed9f497d4a618048a2f56dc97f1): _Similarly to moments, the area is computed using the Green formula. Thus, the returned area and the number of non-zero pixels, if you draw the contour using `drawContours` or `fillPoly`, can be different._ I actually observed that several times and don't use `contourArea` anymore for tasks, where I need an "exact" area. For fast iterating/filtering several contours, it's still useful though.

Comment: Then draw your filled contour on a black image and use np.count_nonzeros().

Comment: Sorry for late answer. I was not here. I solved this issue with using `cv2.countNonZero` Thanks for all answers.